# Accessing LDA parameters from Apache Mahout LDA package

Tags: apache, mahout

I have just tested using Apache Mahout for building an Latent dirichlet allocation model on a corpus of 30 documents. I did not have Hadoop installed on the system thats why a local execution of the Mahout yielded the resulting model. I would like to access the model parameters, as in the estimated \alpha, \beta, \Phi, \Theta

How can I access these?

/mahout lda -i /tf-vectors -o  -k 4-v 27

I can see that  has folder  for each iteration(i presume) of the learning algorithm. Each  has a single file part-r-0000 which I do not know how to access.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you off-hand except to say that the people who can help you all 
read the mahout-user mailing list and answer questions there.  I suggest you
repeat your question there.

See here for more information about how to subscribe: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/mailing-lists.html